# How to sort a column holding roman numbers using Pagination in Cakephp 2.x

Tags: php, sorting, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.x

I have a field (radio buttons) to select a century.

So when I show a list of my fields in the view, I can sort the columns (ASC or DESC), but roman numerals are strings with these options:

```
(XVI, XVII, XVIII, XIX, XX, XXI)
```

Is there any way to tell paginator to use a custom `usort` function, but just for that column?

I already have a function to convert and sort the romans, but how can I use it along with the paginator sort function in the view?

CakePHP 2.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do the sorting at the database level, so `usort()` won't help.

A possible solution is to do the following:

1. Create a MySQL **user defined function** to convert roman numerals to arabic numbers. A few are provided in the following question:

   - [MySQL Custom Function to Turn Roman Numeral Into Arabic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004959/mysql-custom-function-to-turn-roman-numeral-into-arabic)

.

2. **Create a virtual field** that uses this function to return the century in numeric format:

   ```
   public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
       parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
       $this->virtualFields['century_number'] = sprintf('convert_to_number(%s.century))', $this->alias);
   }
   ```
3. **Use this virtual field to sort** the results in your pagination.
   CakePHP can handle this, as stated in the Cookbook 2.x: [Pagination and virtual fields](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html#pagination-and-virtual-fields).

Although the above works, perhaps it would make things easier if you stored the centuries in a numeric field type (or as a date). Converting to roman numerals can be easily done in the view.

Comment: Awesome, that worked very well. In my case was for postgresql, but same result =) Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes, I ended up thinking that i could also have the same result using CASE and WHEN in the virtual fields like:

`$this->virtualFields['century_number'] =
            "CASE WHEN (Century.century_number = 'XVI') THEN '" . XVI . "'
                  WHEN (Century.century_number = 'XVII') THEN '" . XVII . "'
            ELSE '' END";`

but only when you have a few values to compare =)